# Google tags manager don't load any cookies

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

For some reason, the Google Tags Manager does not load any cookies when added dynamically

When the user clicks on some accept button I add a `script` tag to the `body` with the `src` of `https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=${GOOGLE_TAGS_ID}` and after it has been loaded I ran this:

```
function gtag(...args: any[]) {
  window.dataLayer.push(args);
}

// After the script has finish loading I called this function
function load() {
  gtag('js', new Date());
  gtag('config', GOOGLE_TAGS_ID);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TL;DR `gtag` function should be global and use the [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) object

---

The problem was the `gtag` function I defined

The code that you should add to your HTML page was this:

```html
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=<id>"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){ dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());
  gtag('config', '<id>');
</script>
```

##### 2 Problems my `gtag` function had:

1. It wasn't global (maybe wasn't a problem but it's different then the original implementation).
2. I used the [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) (`...args`) instead of using the [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) object.

   Because rest parameters and the `arguments` object are not the same, as explained at [*MDN - The difference between rest parameters and the arguments object*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters#the_difference_between_rest_parameters_and_the_arguments_object)

In most circumstances, you should prefer to use the rest parameters over `arguments` object, but apparently, *Google Tags Manager* needs the properties of the `arguments` object.

So what I did was:

```
// The function is usually done in the script tag within the global scope, so we adding the function to the global scope
window.gtag = function gtag(...args: any[]) {
  // The original function was without the ...args, we added it so TypeScript won't scream

  // Use arguments instead of the rest parameter
  // See why here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/69185535/5923666
  // TL;DR: arguments contain some data that not passed in the rest parameters
  window.dataLayer.push(arguments);
}
```