# How can I run specific tests or everything without strict mode in jests

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, strict

Is there a way to disable the strict mode (although I didn't turn it on) for the specific test?

I have a function that pushes the [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) object to an array.
In my test, I need to check the array content

(I must use the `arguments` object as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69185535/5923666))

**Code:**

```
// file.ts

function gtag() {
  window.dataLayer.push(arguments);
}

// Tested function
export function load() {
  gtag('js', new Date());
}
```

**Test:**

```
// file.test.ts

import { export } from './file.ts';

it('should push to the array an arguments object with js and the config', () => {
  // Act    
  load();

  // Assert
  expect(window.dataLayer).toHaveLength(1);
  expect(window.dataLayer[0]).toHaveLength(2);
  expect(window.dataLayer[0][0]).toEqual('js');
  expect(window.dataLayer[0][1]).toEqual(expect.any(Date));

  // Test Fail here:
  expect(window.dataLayer[0]).toHaveProperty('callee');
});
```

But the test fails with the error:

```
TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them
```

Cause I accessed `callee` in the `arguments` object.

What I know (and tried):

- I can't disable strict mode per function as explain [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020178/can-i-disable-ecmascript-strict-mode-for-specific-functions)

  but this is running under jest, maybe there is a way to turn it off for certain tests

- *Module code is always strict mode code.* From [EMCAScript 2015](https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-strict-mode-code)

  But it didn't work even when I:

  - Changed all the code in the code file from `export` to `module.exports`
  - Replace `import` by `require` in the test file (as suggested [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3318#issuecomment-340198741))
  - Added to my `tsconfig.json` under `compilerOptions` the options:

    - `"strict": false`
    - `"noImplicitUseStrict": true`

---

If it changes anything, I use TypeScript and this test is in React project but I test pure JS/TS code and don't import any React/other files in my tested file

```
// index.tsx
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Why use `arguments` anyway? Especially now that spread/rest operators exist. `gtag(...args) { window.dataLayer.push(args); }`

Comment: I've updated my question with why